# select on result of subtract. mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Assume there is collection like:

```
db.test.insert([{"f1":100,"f2":150},{"f1":120,"f2":541},{"f1":125,"f2":140}])
```

How can I create similar query mongodb

```
Select count(*) from test where  (f2-f1)<100
```

I did some tries, but not work:

```
db.test.aggregate([{ $match: {} }, { $project: { _id : 0,name : 1, r1: {$subtract:["$f2", "$f1"]} }}])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First use `$project` to create a result-set with the calculated values. Then use `$match` to filter out those values which don't match your condition.

```
db.test.aggregate(
    { $project: { _id : 0,
                  name : 1, 
                  difference: {$subtract:["$f2", "$f1"]}
                }
    },
    { $match: { difference: { $lt: 100 }
              }
    })
```